# what is this blue mint/lemonbalm?

Tags: identification, mint

The person who gave me this plant, thinks its a variety of Melissa (lemonbalm), 
can't find anything similar on the internet,

**it has a very pleasant and strong candy smell, something like a mix of Barberry and Mint** ( tea will retain the smell )

here's pictures of it in my garden:

[image: blue melissa]
[image: zoomed in picture]

[image: more zoomed picture]

Comment: It look like sage. Just to be sure, does it smell of sage?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it smells like sweet candy something like a mix of Barberry and Mint, and we make tea from it, it's not sage

Comment: Yeah the first few pictures looked like Sage but I think they're not Sage too. Sage tends to be bushy/shrubby. The zoomed pictures seem to be like individual herbs.

Comment: Also, you may want to try "PictureThis" app to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @perennial_noob thnx for the app suggestion, unfortunately the app identifies it as sage, purple mint, and lambs ears

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Mentha longifolia (example here: https://www.norfolkherbs.co.uk/product/mint-buddleia-mentha-longifolia/)

Used to have it in my garden by the name “forest mint” or “uzbek mint”.

Comment: I did a google image search with "Mentha Longifolia" and it doesn't seem to be it, this has a whitish turquoise colour and the teeth on the edge of the leaf are almost unnoticeable